# Why Gitflow Diagram Using mermaid js can't render two git branches in the live editor

Tags: git, mermaid

[mermaid.js live editor link](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/edit#pako:eNqtVcuSgjAQ_JVUzq6KR867tR-wVy5DMkJKSNg4sXyU_74goC7yiLtyzHS6Z3q6yIkLI5GHPFH0aaFII83qT5g8V8SUDFnElVakIGsOI35FxRa0SJnEHWam6B5_w5vEIjOHHny3IlIUG-NoiGuNQM7iYn849vdYFpg0Gu-6u-fs6uVoE5xmhaxIgRFuSemkj3qSIXbJWu37rj7a49lUjDTaU9dCT9rKwQtUMqXJXGke1m0xQ9jiYhfMl_NlP1lda6EsMwlzhQRCGXFGkNwwfRPkoHSn_SdEC2ukE6SMbm_5u_Qqmcaqevvjng8nZDC3U7R1nd3S-0z-PMmvKfQ319-NJogT2QtG9hN4ZC_4S_bGRV-WvVfI_BqlMTA1VO3gwrMa0Vg1yI5lK0_L_GX-49izw9TXHlPV_hshFgPvQCzuXhc-4yVRObUsn85TdRJxSjEvyxVYgt1UwHOJq4P3IRUZy8M1ZFuccXBkvg5a8JCswxb0riCxkDeo8w_PtFyn)

So I'm designing a gitflow diagram using mermaid js in the live environment. All the things are working fine but suddenly I notice two of my git branches `hotfix/v1.0.2` & `feature/abc` is not showing up in the preview. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. I'm a beginner & this is my first time using mermaid so can anyone help me to identify what am I doing wrong here?

```
gitGraph
   commit id: "initial commit"
   branch develop
   branch qa-deploy
   branch dev-deploy
   checkout develop
   branch feature/xyz
   commit id: "xyz done"
   checkout dev-deploy
   merge feature/xyz
   commit id: "alpha testing"
   checkout feature/xyz
   commit id: "bugfix"
   checkout qa-deploy
   merge feature/xyz
   commit id: "beta testing"
   checkout develop
   merge feature/xyz
   commit id: "xyz merged into develop"
   branch release/v1.0.0
   commit id: "v1.0.0 release log updated" tag: "v1.0.0"
   checkout main
   merge release/v1.0.0
   commit id: "v1.0.0 production release"
   checkout develop
   merge release/v1.0.0
   commit id: "v1.0.0 production release"
   branch bugfix/xyz
   commit id: "xyz bugfix"
   checkout dev-deploy
   merge bugfix/xyz
   commit id: "bugfix alpha test"
   checkout qa-deploy
   merge bugfix/xyz
   commit id: "bugfix beta test"
   checkout develop
   merge bugfix/xyz
   commit id: "xyz bugfix merged"
   branch release/v1.0.1
   commit id: "v1.0.1 release log updated" tag: "v1.0.1"
   checkout main
   merge release/v1.0.1
   commit id: "v1.0.1 production release"
   checkout develop
   merge release/v1.0.1
   commit id: "v1.0.1 production release"
   checkout main
   branch hotfix/v1.0.2
   commit id: "v1.0.2 hotfix" tag: "v1.0.2"
   checkout main
   merge hotfix/v1.0.2
   commit id: "v1.0.2 production release"
   checkout develop
   merge hotfix/v1.0.2
   commit id: "v1.0.2 hotfix merge"
   branch feature/abc
   commit id: "abc done"
```